# How do I convert return series in Pandas DataFrame to price series?

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I have a Pandas DataFrame consisting of asset price returns and want to create a new DataFrame that will convert those returns into price series. How do I do that?

The original returns dataframe is:

```
      0     1     2
0  0.01  0.02  0.04
1  0.02  0.05  0.04
```

I want to index the original price for all series at 100.00 so that I get the following dataframe:

```
      0     1       2
0  100.00 100.00 100.00
1  101.00 102.00 104.00
2  103.02 107.10 108.16
```

Comment: It might be worth it to structure your request with original df with multiple sample datapoints, output returned, expected output. The way im reading this, its hard to id what exactly your looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to calculate the interest relative to the starting value. This is done easily using `cumprod()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [0.01, 0.02], 1: [0.02,0.05], 2:[0.04, 0.04]})
relative_returns = (df+1).cumprod()

#         0      1       2
# 0  1.0100  1.020  1.0400
# 1  1.0302  1.071  1.0816
```

To calculate the final value, we can multiply by the initial value:

```
final_value = 100*relative_returns


#         0      1       2
# 0  101.00  102.0  104.00
# 1  103.02  107.1  108.16
```

Rearranging the table will result in the exact form you require.

*The rearranging can be done before the process above as follows:*

```
df = df.append(
        pd.Series(np.nan, index=df.columns, name=df.index.max()+1)
     ).shift().fillna(0.0)

#       0     1     2
# 0  0.00  0.00  0.00
# 1  0.01  0.02  0.04
# 2  0.02  0.05  0.04
```

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you very much for your help.